# Send multiples params securely to IN clause with Sequelize for raw query

Tags: javascript, sql, security, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize I can perform raw queries and send params securely (thanks to database bound params via parameters:

```js
const baz = 1;

sequelize.query(
  'select * from foo where bar=:baz',
  { replacements: { baz } },
);
```

Is there a similar way to address the `IN` (with multiple values)?

```js
const baz = [1, 2, 3];

sequelize.query(
  'select * from foo where bar IN (:baz)',
  { replacements: { baz } },
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html):

> Array replacements will automatically be handled, the following query searches for projects where the status matches an array of values

So this should actually work:

```js
const baz = [1, 2, 3];

sequelize.query(
  'select * from foo where bar IN (:baz)',
  { replacements: { baz } },
);
```