# How to bind an array to a parameter used alongside IN operator in sequelize query

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I had to write a custom postgres sql query, so I used `sequelize.query` method. But I am a bit lost in how I can bind an array to a parameter used alongside an `IN` operator. The current code looks something like this, with obviously doesn't work.

```
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM students WHERE grade IN $grades', {
  bind: { grades: ['A+', 'A'] },
  type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send multiples params securely to IN clause with Sequelize for raw query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64554295/send-multiples-params-securely-to-in-clause-with-sequelize-for-raw-query)

Comment: IN works with lists, not arrays.  To use an array, write it as `WHERE grade =ANY($grades)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `= any` instead of `in`. Change the query text to

```sql
SELECT * FROM students WHERE grade = any(string_to_array($grades, ','))
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM students WHERE grade = any(('{'||$grades||'}')::text[])
```

and bind `grades` as a string, `'A+,A'`.
The second option works for other data types too.